# Getting error while running php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am getting the below error while running the below command.
**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

```
Class "Magento\Framework\HTTP\LaminasClient" does not exist                                                                                                
  Class Webkul\Marketplace\Controller\Account\Dashboard\Tunnel\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'ge  
  nerated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission  
   is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construc  
  t method, only.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because generated dictionary does not have sufficient write permission.

Give 777 permission to generated folder

Then run command again.

Please let me know still if you get issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when there is a problem with the generated code in Magento 2. Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

1. Check file permissions: Make sure the 'generated' directory is writable by the web server user. You can use the command `chmod -R 777 generated` to give full permissions to the generated directory.
2. Clean cache: Run the command `bin/magento cache:clean` to clear the Magento cache.
3. Compile code: Run the command `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to generate new code. Make sure the generated directory is writable before running this command.
4. Check for errors: Check the Magento logs for any errors or exceptions related to this issue. You can find the logs in the var/log directory of your Magento installation.

If none of the above steps work, you can try disabling the module that is causing the issue and then re-enabling it. You can also try disabling all third-party modules and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check your commerce version.

`Magento\Framework\HTTP\LaminasClient` is introduced in commerce version `2.4.6`. Seems like the webkul marketplace version you are using is compatible to 2.4.6.